# Ayuda con función parseInt()

Tags: javascript, funciones

En un problema para resolver el siguiente problema

Pregúntale a una niña pequeña: "¿Cuántos años tienes?". Ella siempre dice cosas extrañas ... ¡Vamos a ayudarla!
Para el programa de respuesta correcta, debe devolver int de 0 a 9;)
Supongamos que la cadena de entrada de prueba siempre es válida y puede parecerse a "1 año de edad" o "5 años de edad", etc. El primer carácter es solo número.

y la solución es la siguiente pero no entiendo bien el porqué, me podrían explicar el por qué.

```
function getAge(inputString){
  return parseInt(inputString.charAt(0));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

La función recibe el string (La cadena que se ingresa), como el primer carácter es un numero que significara la edad de la niña, se recoge con `inputString.charAt(0)` que implica la letra 0 de una cadena.

**Ejemplo**
"4años", el numero "4" es la letra 0, la letra "a" es la letra 1, y así sucesivamente.

entonces con la función `parseInt()` esta recibiendo el resultado de `inputString.charAt(0)` que es "4" de tipo string, entonces `parseInt("4")` transforma el numero 4 a tipo integer (numerico)

Comment: Gracias Santiago por la información, lo entendí a la perfección.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que esa función hace es recibir una cadena de texto como respuesta que como indicas puede ser "1 año", entonces charAt(0) lo que hace es capturar el primer valor de esa cadena ya que le pones el parámetro "0" , que de la cadena "1 año" seria "1" y lo parsea (cambia de tipo de dato) de string a int (entero) de esta manera podrás realizar operaciones matemáticas con la edad de la niña.

Comment: Muchas gracias Hugo por la explicación me ha quedado claro.